# "Skip Navigation" Link without anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

I am trying to create a "skip navigation" link without being able to use anchors. The site is built in a peculiar way, where anchor link formatting has been re-purposed. So, I am attempting to allow people to skip the navigation by using focus. However, it isn't working.

HTML code for the skip navigation link itself:

```
<!-- Start Top Left in Nav Bar -->
<aside>
<a href="" onClick="javascript:skipNav()" tabindex="1" id="skipNav" role="link">Skip Navigation</a>
</aside>
<!-- End Top Left in Nav Bar -->
```

Code to Change the Focus

```
var nav = document.getElementById('#skipNav');
nav.onclick=skipNav();

function skipNav(){
     document.activeElement.blur();

    if ($('#linkHome').hasClass('current')==true)
    {
        $('#homeFocus').focus();
    }
    if ($('#linkTeam').hasClass('current')==true)
    {
        $('#teamFocus').focus();
    }
    if ($('#linkTraining').hasClass('current')==true)
    {
        $('#trainingFocus').focus();
    }
    if ($('#linkTesting').hasClass('current')==true)
    {
        $('#testingFocus').focus();
    }
    if ($('#linkRemediation').hasClass('current')==true)
    {
        $('#remediationFocus').focus();
    }
    if ($('#linkContact').hasClass('current')==true)
    {
        $('#contactFocus').focus();
    }

};
```

Script to Change Pages and Mark Current Page

```
var FluidNav = {
init: function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]) {
            FluidNav.goTo($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]);
        }
    });
    this.goTo("home");
},
goTo: function(page) {
    var next_page = $("#"+page);
    var nav_item = $('nav ul li a[href=#'+page+']');
    $("nav ul li").removeClass("current");
    nav_item.parent().addClass("current");
    FluidNav.resizePage((next_page.height() + 40), true, function() {
         $(".page").removeClass("current"); next_page.addClass("current"); 
    });
    $(".page").fadeOut(500);
    next_page.fadeIn(500);
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $('#'+page+'Focus').focus();

    FluidNav.centerArrow(nav_item);

},
centerArrow: function(nav_item, animate) {
    var left_margin = (nav_item.parent().position().left + nav_item.parent().width()) + 24 - (nav_item.parent().width() / 2);
    if(animate != false) {
        $("nav .arrow").animate({
            left: left_margin - 8
        }, 500, function() { $(this).show(); });
    } else {
        $("nav .arrow").css({ left: left_margin - 8 });
    }
},
resizePage: function(size, animate, callback) {
    if(size) { var new_size = size; } else { var new_size = $(".page.current").height() + 40; }
    if(!callback) { callback = function(){}; }
    if(animate) {
        $("#pages").animate({ height: new_size }, 400, function() { callback.call(); }); 
    } else {
        $("#pages").css({ height: new_size }); 
    }
}
};

 $("nav select").change(function() {
    if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != "#") {
        var page = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value.split("#")[1];
        FluidNav.goTo(page);
        $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop:$('#'+page).offset().top }, 700);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `document.getElementById('#skipNav')` isnt going to work... anyways, why are you using the old school when you're using jQuery? And if the question is how to do this without using an anchor tag, why is your initial sample using an `a` tag? This question is confusing.

Comment: Did you know that clicking `<a href="#someid">skip</a>` will take the user to any element with `id="someid"`?

Comment: Tejs & Blazemonger, the person who created the original code for this website harvested the anchor tag functionality. So, while things look like anchor links, they actually go, as Blazemonger found, to another page. This site is constructed as a single page that scrolls to the 'desired' content (ie, the content on each div defined 'page') and hides all the other content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to do a 'dynamic skiplink', where you determine the target at runtime?

```
<a href="" onClick="javascript:skipNav()" tabindex="1" id="skipNav" role="link">Skip Navigation</a>
```

The problem is that when you click a link, navigation happens. A `href=""` doesn't prevent navigation, it just means that you end up navigating to the current page - and that's going to reset the focus. This happens after your click event handler. So even though you may correctly set the focus where you want to, it ends up being 'lost' when the page reloads.

There's a couple of ways to prevent this: one is to use `href="javascript:void(0)"` - `href` specifies where to navigate, and if it evaluates to void, the browser won't navigate at all.

A somewhat cleaner way is to tell the browser not to carry out the default action in the event handler:

```
function skipNav(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action - link navigation - from taking place
    ...
```

--

Couple of other issues with the code:

Don't bother with `role="link"` on the `A` - save these attributes for when you are doing something out of the ordinary. The key thing to know is that screenreaders already know how to deal with all the standard HTML elements when they are used in a standard way. So if you are using an  as a link, or a  as a button, then you don't need to add a role.

But if you are creating a new control of of plain DIVs, or if you are repurposing a HTML element for a different use, then you need a role attribute to tell the screenreader how you are *actually* using the element.

For example, a DIV that's had an onclick handler and is behaving like a button would need role="button", otherwise a screenreader might ignore it or just say something generic like 'element'. Or if you are creating a button from an A tag, and it ends up behaving like and looking like a button from a user's point of view, then you'd need role="button" so that a screenreader will announce it as a button rather than as a link.

--

Watch for mixing plain DOM vs jQuery conventions - only jQuery uses # to find elements by ID, so use either:

```
var nav = document.getElementById('skipNav'); // plain DOM way, no #
```

or

```
var nav = $('#skipnav'); // jQuery way using selector
```

--

Watch for functions as values vs calls:

```
nav.onclick=skipNav();
```

This will actually *call* `skipNav()`, and assign the return value - null! - to onclick. Don't use ()'s when you're setting a callback. You don't need this code anyhow, since you're setting the handler using onClick in the  tag anyhow.

Also, note that as your code stands, when skipNav() is called, it tries to call document.activeElement.blur() - but at that point in time - document is still loading - there's no activeElement, so calling blur() on null generates an exception - which you should see in your browser's console/debugging window.

--

Don't use .blur() - there's no need to do this:

```
 document.activeElement.blur();
```

Instead, just focus the element you want to have focus. The danger with doing .blur() is that if the code after it fails to set the focus somewhere reasonable, focus will end up getting 'lost', which is very inconvenient for a keyboard user, since they have to tab from the start of the page.

--

Javascript coding practice: don't bother with `== true` in the if() expressions; and unless you expect you expect more than one of the elements to have the 'current' class, use `else if` instead of plain `if`: this makes it clear in the code that you're expecting only one branch to be used.

--

Finally, make friends with the browser's debugger (F12 in most): you'll learn some of the above by putting breakpoints in the event handler and your initialization code, and stepping through it to ensure it's behaving as you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointers. I'm not naturally a coder, I'm afraid. I will, however, have to improve my technique and the tips are very much appreciated.I did have a question about the roles. I understand that for the code, I probably wouldn't need the role on most tags. However, I was including them for accessibility with screen readers. Is it still unnecessary to put them everywhere possible?

Comment: @Tirithe - you're welcome! I've updated the answer to include more details on the role attribute that should answer your question. Basic idea is - don't add theme *everywhere possible*; only add them where *needed*: save them for when you are creating new controls from SPANs or DIVs, or using an HTML element in an unusual way. But there's no reason to add role="link" to an A, or role="button" to a button - screenreaders already know what those tags are.